# how to move a section below another using margin property in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin

i have an html page, which have a lot of sections in homepage, I have two sections like below:

```html
<div class='first section'>
  <a href=''>
    <button style='background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc99ff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);'>

          <h3> HMT Rice</h3>
          </button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class='second section'>
  <a href=''>
    <button style='background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc99ff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);'>

          <h3> PKS Rice</h3>
          </button>
  </a>
</div>
```

I used margin-top property to bring first section a little bit lower, but its just creating a white space above and also.

i just want to make the first section below second section using css just like image below:

[image]
is there anyway to bring the first section directly below using z-index or something. please help. thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of margin, use padding-top. I've seen this kind of problem before.

Comment: @MurtazaJAFARI it also creating white space above and just taking all the elements go down , just like margin top

Comment: please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the following HTML and CSS.

```css
.section{
    position: relative;
}
.second_section{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.first_section{
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 70px; /* Adjust this margin top pixed according to the space you needed. */
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
    <div class="first_section">
      <a href=''>
        <button style='background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc99ff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);'>

          <h3> HMT Rice</h3>
          </button>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="second_section">
      <a href=''>
        <button style='background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc99ff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);'>

          <h3> PKS Rice</h3>
          </button>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I have fixed the problem in your site by inspecting element. Please follow below code.**

You should wrap the buttons div and slider div with **slide-button-wrapper** div   and add the css.

```
<div class="slide-button-wrapper">            
    <div class="mainsme" id="grid">

      <h2 style="font-size:28px;">Shop by Category</h2>
      <div class="gridmine">
         <!---buttons will goes here-->
      </div>

    </div>
                     
    <div class="main-row slider-section" style="order: 1;">
        <banner codes are here>
    </div>
</div>


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .slide-button-wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        
        .mainsme{
          order: 2;
        }
        .slider-section{
          order: 1
        }`
    }
```

Comment: this is not working bro, this is still giving a white space in the section and taking all section down

Comment: do you wrapped first_section and second_section div with <div class="section">?

Comment: yes bro, actually the website is built in opencart, there is no way to edit the code from backend, i placed an HTML section using editor, i want to re arrange the section below one section

Comment: I have experience on opencart. Can you share your website url?

Comment: pls give the page url where that two buttons

Comment: its in the homepage, please access it using mobile, you will see in the front itself, with a colorful grid, heading 'shop by category', I need to move it below the slider

Comment: I have fixed the problem in your site by inspecting element. I have updated my answare. Please check it.

Comment: but bro, am not able to edit the slider div, because in my homepage only the main div is there, and its showing <div id="content"><?PHP echo content?></div> in this code the whole page is coming including section, I just added my grid inside this content div, I am not able find from where the slider or other data in the page is coming from

Comment: try to find out the section from where the slider and buttons are coming.

Comment: slider is default, buttons i created and kept in home

Comment: slider is default but its generating from somewhere. try to find out from where it is originated.

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange elements using the [order property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp)

**Note** that the parent must be `display: flex;`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.first {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  order: 2;
}

.second {
  order: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">first</div>
  <div class="second">second</div>
</div>
```